# Como hacer operaciones con campos de tablas en mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un formulario que manda datos a una tabla en mysql llamada (regis) y tiene los campos(Nombre, Direccion, Telefono, Id_trabajo, Cantidad, Fecha_ingreso, Anticipo), en mi campo (Id_trabajo) va el value de mi option selected,ya que coloque un campo con varias opciones y les coloque (1,2,3,etc)dependiendo cual escogan

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<div class="col-md-5">
      <select class="form-control"  name="txt2">
       
        <option selected value="0"> Elige una opcion </option>
        <optgroup label="Porcelana">
        <option value="1">Corona metal porcelana</option>
        <option value="2">Corona veneer</option>
        <option value="3">Corona meriland</option>
        <option value="4">Montado de porcelana</option>
        </optgroup>
```

Tengo otra tabla llamada (trabajos) con los campos (id, codigo, nombre,costo)que muestro en mi pagina,que funciona como una lista de precios,el usuario puede modificar los costos,eliminar u agregar un nuevo producto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora lo que quiero hacer, es que al buscar un determinado cliente por nombre,me aparezca la siguiente informacion desplegada,

(Nombre, Direccion, telefono, fecha de ingreso, Nombre del trabajo,Costo, Cantidad, Total,Anticipo,Resta),

en mi campo "Nombre del trabajo", quiero que salga el nombre dependiendo del valor del campo (Id_trabajo),por ejemplo, en la tabla que les moestre primero el valor en el campo Id_trabajo es el 1, el cual corresponde al nombre "corona metal pòrcelana", de la tabla "trabajos",por que tiene el id=1,no se si se entiende?

y pues para llenar el campo Costo y Total,necesito hacer la operacion  dependiendo del Id_trabajo de la tabla 1, por ejemplo en mi tabla tengo el 1, que corresponde al id=1 de la tabla "trabajos" el cual tiene el costo de $500, entonces para el Total seria 500 por 2, que es el valor del campo "Cantidad" de la tabla 1

Como puedo hacer esas operaciones y mostrarlas en la tabla? o que metodos puedo usar?

Les dejo mi código que tengo, es un select de mi tabla regis, pero me faltan campos de llenar,quiero que salga toda la información que les mecione y que de igual manera se guarde,para posteriormente poder modificarla,pero no se como

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
 
 <? include("config.php");
 //Instaciamos la clase de base de datos
  $db = new Clasedb();
  //Llamamos a la funcion para conectar a la base de datos
  $db->MySQL();
  //Consultamos la tabla regis
  $consulta = $db->consulta("SELECT * FROM regis where Nombre like '%$buscar%'");
 ?>
<form class="form-horizontal" name="form1" method="post" action="consultar.php">
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 
 <fieldset class="scheduler-border">
  <legend class="scheduler-border">CONSULTA DE REGISTROS</legend>
   <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-5">
     <input  class="form-control" type="text" name="buscar" placeholder="nombre del cliente">
    </div>
   </div>
   <button class="btn btn-primary">BUSCAR</button>
 </fieldset>
 
 
 
 <?php
 
 if($_POST['buscar'])
 {
  ?>
  <br>
 
 <div class="table-responsive">
 <div class="container" id="container1" style="padding-top: 1em;">
     <table class="table table-hover  table-condensed">
        <thead>
    <tr>
  
     <th class="col-sm-2">Nombre</th>
     <th class="col-sm-1">Direcc</th>
     <th class="col-sm-1">Tel</th>
     <th class="col-sm-1">Fecha de ingreso</th>
     <th class="col-sm-1">Nombre trabajo</th>
     <th class="col-sm-1">Costo</th>
     <th class="col-sm-1">Unidad</th>
     <th class="col-sm-1">Total</th>
     <th class="col-sm-1">Anticipo</th>
     <th class="col-sm-1">Resta</th>
     <th class="col-sm-1">Editar</th>
     <th class="col-sm-1">Eliminar</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
 <?php
 while($resultado = $db->obtenerfilas($consulta))
  
  {?>
      <tr>
     <td class="Nombre"><?=$resultado['Nombre']?></td>
     <td class="Direccion"><?=$resultado['Direccion']?></td>
     <td class="Telefonos"><?=$resultado['Telefono']?></td>
     <td class="Fecha_ingreso"><?=$resultado['Fecha_ingreso']?></td>
     <td class="Tipo_trabajo"><?=$resultado['Id_trabajo']?></td>
     <td class="Costo_uni"><?=$resultado['Costo_uni']?></td>
     <td class="Cantidad"><?=$resultado['Cantidad']?></td>
     <td clas="Total"><?=$resultado['Total']?></td>
     <td class="Anticipo"><?=$resultado['Anticipo']?></td>
     <td clas="Resta"><?=$resultado['Resta']?></td>
     
     <td class="Editar"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dataUpdate" data-id="<?php echo $row['id']?>"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></i></button></td>
             

             <td class="Eliminar"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dataDelete" data-id="<?php echo $row['id']?>"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i></button></td>
  
    </tr>
  <? } ?>  <!--Cierra el while-->
  </table>
 </div> <!--Cierra el container-->
 </div>
  <br>
  <?php

  }echo "";

  ?>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: podrias dejar el codigo donde haces las operaciones y creas la variable `$resultado`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto claramente es con un *JOIN*.

Puedes hacer la siguiente query y ejecutarla en Phpmyadmin o la plataforma que utilices:

```
SELECT
  * 
FROM 
  regis AS R
JOIN
  trabajos AS T
ON
  R.id_trabajo = T.id
```

Te devolverá todos los registros que tengan el mismo id_trabajo.

si quieres un registro en específico, sólo agrega un where:

```
WHERE
  id_cliente = 1
```

Por poner un valor al *WHERE*, ya lo colocas en tu código. Por ejemplo, si el id_cliente lo obtienes por *POST*, y en resúmen, sería así:

```
$id_cliente = $_POST['id_cliente'];

$query = "
  SELECT
      * 
    FROM 
      regis AS R
    JOIN
      trabajos AS T
    ON
      R.id_trabajo = T.id 
 WHERE
      id_cliente = $id_cliente ";
```

Por otra parte, si lo obtienes del campo de búsqueda entonces te quedaría así:

```
$query = "
      SELECT
          * 
        FROM 
          regis AS R
        JOIN
          trabajos AS T
        ON
          R.id_trabajo = T.id 
     WHERE
          nombre LIKE '%$nombre_cliente%' ";
```

Ejecutas la query, obtienes el resultado y ya lo imprimes. Comentas si te funcionó.

**Nota:** este es un ejemplo con fines didácticos. Nunca uses variables de procedencia del usuario sin validarlas, como valores de POST o GET, pues puedes ser vulnerable a inyección SQL. Para evitar esto, usa validaciones de tipo de dato (int para id's, string para otros campos, etc), de ser necesario sanarlas ([settype](http://php.net/manual/es/function.settype.php) o [FILTER_VAR](http://php.net/manual/es/function.filter-var.php)) y usa un método de Mysqli llamado [real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php); o usa [sentencias preparadas.](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: si me funciono,muchas gracias,solo que tengo unas dudas, en el query, que pusiste el (AS R join trabajos AS T) eso tu lo defines?,puede ser otro nombre?

Comment: y por ejemplo cuando ejecuto la consulta me salen todos los campos de esas dos tablas,como puedo hacer para que no salgan todos,solo los que yo quiero, y ya que muestro esos datos, como los guardo en otra tabla, para que yo posteriormente los pueda editar y se actualizen, porque pues solo se esta haciendo la consulta

Comment: Sí, es un alias para que sql reconozca a R como la tabla registro. En realidad, puedes colocar la letra que quieras pero lo ideal es que sea la primera de letra del nombre de la tabla para que la ubiques mejor.

Sobre los campos, sí puedes elegir cuáles deseas. Por ejemplo, si quieres un campo de regis, usando el alias sería: 

R.nombre. 

El alias es opcional, es lo mismo si pones

regis.nombre 

E igual para trabajos. 

Entonces:

SELECT R.nombre, T.codigo FROM regis AS R JOIN trabajos AS T ON R.id_trabajo = T.id

Investiga más sobre JOIN. 

Saludos.

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias